# Use xcodebuild to build an iOS app to run on the mac using the "Designed for iPhone" variant

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1, mac-catalyst, apple-silicon

I want to build a "Designed for iPhone" app to run on an Apple Silicon Mac.

running `xcodebuild -showdestinations` gives me a fitting destination

```
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008112-000E54C126F9401E }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:25EFC1E1-1C64-4A9F-9EF5-28AD20DDCA79, OS:16.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
```

building for the -destination "id:00008112-000E54C126F9401E" build something, but just creates a iOS bundle, no macOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get `xcodebuild` to build a Mac app for me, but I was able to slap together a mac app that runs on the developer machine anyway:
build an iOS release version of your app and put it in a directory structure that looks like this:

```
RunOnMac.app/
├── WrappedBundle -> Wrapper/RunOnMac.app
└── Wrapper
    └── RunOnMac.app
```